# Dilink dir 600 m Wifi repeater showing no internet access

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater

In Dlink dir 600m router wifi repeater is connected but showing no internet access i have gone through most of articles online but no solution ...Can some get best fix for it ? And some times router page is not opening

Comment: Are you able to ping your router? Do you get an IP in the needed adress range?

Comment: I have found that Windows 10 connects without internet access if I use WEP security. Do you use this OS and wireless setting?

Comment: my main router ip address is 192.168.01 and repeater ip is 192.168.0.2.. ama able to ping both ips and gettinfg response for that but internet is not coming in repeater but when i connect to main rouer able to access internet

Comment: i do use windows 10 os and use wep sucurity for password.. i have tried without password also in my mobile it is showing no internet access